# How do I allow saving in safe places only?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I allow saving in safe places only? e.g. Your home, tavern, or only in your bed? I am playing Skyrim on the PC. Is there a mod, console command or another solution that can allow this?

Comment: Ummmm.... How is asking how to save off-topic?

Comment: @Angus The original question asking for a mod suggestion was off-topic.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Is this about the creation of a mod?

Comment: @DavidYell The question was about a mod, but edited because it was closed for that reason. Now it doesn't make sense anymore. Don't know why someone would edit like that, but well.

Comment: I don't see why people are closing this as a mod recommendation or being unclear. Solutions to issues for Skyrim on the PC will usually involve mods.

Comment: Here's the name of a mod: Self-Control

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but might help you or other players if no other solution (mod, etc.) is available.

You should consider having more than one save file. Use the first one in safe places, before starting a new quest or before exploring a new region. Then have a second one which you can use to save your current progress, wherever you are at the moment. This solution can also help you if one of your save files becomes corrupted, you will always have a fallback, assuming your save files are not too old.